# Telegram keeps returning a 409, how do I debug this?

Tags: ruby, telegram, long-polling, telegram-bot

I receive the following errors when using ruby `telegram-bot-ruby` with my telegram service:

```
Telegram::Bot::Exceptions::ResponseError: Telegram API has returned the error. (ok: "false", error_code: "409", description: "Conflict: terminated by other long poll or webhook")
```

I am using the desktop to test against both my dev bot and my production bot.  So the chat ID appears to be the same but the bot API's are different.

Other than that, the code seems fine and returns this intermittently.

**Questions:**

1) How do I debug to prevent this from occurring?

2) How can I set up my app to not exit -- it is rescuing into Rollbar, but also exits the script

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like your problem might be because your trying to access the same endpoint within the same ruby process at the same time. To prevent that maybe try spawning a different ruby process for each bot you mentioned like one process for your dev bot and another process for your production bot.

Maybe check out the ruby's Process module is has a method called #fork here: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Process.html#method-c-fork

Comment: The two run with different scripts and different tokens....would it still be the same ruby process?